# jVectorMap mark selected state

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

i found the plugin [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/#overview) and i'm trying to mark the state that i selected with a diferente color

the same way that hover happens, but i what i want is, when clicked, the state keep "active" with some color.

the plugin have some actions like `onRegionClick`:

```
$('#map-teste').vectorMap({
    map: 'br_en',
    onRegionClick: function(event, code){
        alert(code); // return the state
    }
});
```

but i dont have any idea how to do this.

anyone achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the color for selected regions by adding `regionStyle` config parameters to the instantiation of your map. You would also want to set the `regionSelectable` to true:

```
$('#map-teste').vectorMap({
    map: 'br_en',
    onRegionClick: function(event, code){
        alert(code); // return the state
    },
    regionsSelectable: true,
    regionStyle: {
        selected: {
            fill: 'orange'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('#map-teste').vectorMap({
    map: 'br_en',
    onRegionClick: function(event, code){
        $('#map-teste').vectorMap('set', 'colors', code, '#000000');
        alert(code); // return the state
    }
});
```

Works fine for me. This would result in multiple selections with no toggling. If you need it 'toggled' for a 'single-selection' effect, you could do it like this:

```
currentSelected = '';
defaultColor = '#00FF00';
selectedColor = '#FF00FF'; 
maphandle = $('#map-teste'); 

maphandle.vectorMap({
    map: 'br_en',
    onRegionClick: function(event, code){
        if(currentSelected !== code) {
            if(currentSelected !== ''){
                // Deselect, then select new choice
                maphandle.vectorMap('set', 'colors', currentSelected, defaultColor);
                maphandle.vectorMap('set', 'colors', code, selectedColor);
                currentSelected = code;
            } else {
                // Nothing currently selected, go ahead and select
                maphandle.vectorMap('set', 'colors', code, selectedColor);
                currentSelected = code;
            }
        } else {
            // Deselect
            maphandle.vectorMap('set', 'colors', code, defaultColor);
            currentSelected = '';
        }
        alert(code); // return the state
    }
});
```

Hope that helps! :)